# Mocking a function in Jest for express app using ES6

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, es6-modules

I have a file 'userServices.js' that performs all DB-related actions. I want to mock this function to throw an error to test some other function.
The behavior of the mocked function will be different for other tests.

```
export const createUser = async (payload) => {
    try{
        const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(payload.password);
        const user = await User.create({
            ...payload,
            password : hashedPassword,
            requestCount: 0,
        });
        return user;
    }catch(error){
        throw Error(error);
    }
};
```

After reading the docs and few posts I got to know that mocking is different for ES6.

I tried the below in my resgister.test.js:

```
const createUserSpy = jest.spyOn(userServices, 'createUser');
createUserSpy.mock.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('Simulated internal server error');
});


describe('Test API', ()=> {
   const request = supertest.agent(app);
   test('handles internal server error (500)', async () => {

    const payload = {
        data...
     };


    const response = await request.post('/register')
      .send(payload);
    console.log(response);
    // Assertions
    expect(response.status).toBe(500);
    expect(createUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('message', 'Internal server error');
    createUserSpy.mockRestore();
  });
})
```

I tried to move the mock function inside the specific test as well.

Error : TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'createUser' of object '[object Module]'

I tried a few things but none of them worked. It just kept running the actual function.

I have a middleware error handler that will send response 500 - Internal server error. I have tested the routes from Postman, its working as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: add the code that you tried

Comment: I tried the below and I am now getting 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'

`const mockCreateUser = jest.fn((payload) => {
    throw new Error("Simulated mock internal server error")
});


jest.mock('../userServices.js', ()=> {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../userServices.js');
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        createUser : mockCreateUser,
    }
});`

Is there something wrong with the way I am mocking functions?

Comment: please share in the question itself, how your "userServices" is defined and how you are importing it in test file?